# Typescript object spread throws "Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type"

Tags: typescript

The issue is with known keys typescript stops working if you exclude a key from the object. See example:

```
const objectKeys = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(object: T) =>
  Object.keys(object) as (keyof T)[];

const obj = { a: 1, b: 2};
objectKeys(obj) // works fine

const { a, ...rest } = obj;
// Argument of type '{ b: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, unknown>'.
// Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type '{ b: number; }'.(2345)
objectKeys(rest); // ???
```

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUyhA8gIwFYOLAvDAHgBUYEAPKBMAEwhgCVsQAnag6ZgSzDgBoYArmADWYEAHcwAPikAKEJgBcMIgEoYuKTAUYA3ACh9oSLB0aYAbxgBDZQEZ%20aZQCYAvgcTJ0WHPMzqAegCYcRZhOgAzbgRDY2hLG34AOhTmBHjXcx0DIJgAQWY4AQBbKlMImCgATwAHBBgAcisnGDAStARmXRhXBphOOjFYawgITjgwazQAG3qoEBga62ZrUspmbQrqusbGUFZ2KC4efiFRCWkGpP1cgEkachgxiesoATSYCJZK2vqGjm4cD6AxgxQGYx4-TAPx2TRgLTaxQ6XR6V1kzgAzAAWACsqn0nlQmGwUFkaWgqm6uQA-LT9EA).

I just don't understand why this is happening. If you hover over `rest`, it even shows the keys known.

Comment: Wow, interesting.  This is a known issue for *interfaces*, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300, but I've never seen it for the result of rest objects in destructuring assignments.  If the question said "how do I prevent this" I'd say that you should change it to `T extends object` or `T extends Record<string, any>` depending on what you're trying to express with `Record<string, unknown>`.

Comment: @jcalz It's very mysterious indeed. What's even more confusing is that if you do `const x = rest; objectKeys(x)`, the error goes away too: even though `x` and `rest` are absolutely identical and refers to the same object.

Comment: Reassigning `rest` to temporary variable fixes the issue, although I don't know why: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUyhA8gIwFYOLAvDAHgBUYEAPKBMAEwhgCVsQAnag6ZgSzDgBoYArmADWYEAHcwAPikAKEJgBcMIgEoYuKTAUYA3ACh9oSLB0aYAbxgBDZQEZ+aZQCYYAXwOJk6LDnmZ1AHpAmHEWYToAM24EQ2NoSxt+ADpU5gQEt3MdA2CYAEFmOAEAWypTSJgoAE8ABwQYAHIrJxgwUrQEZl13RphOOjFYawgITjgwazQAGwaoEBha62ZrMspmbUqa+qbGUFZ2KC4efiFRCWlG5P08gEkachgxiesoAXSYSJYquobGjm4cD6AxgJQGYx4-TAPx2zRgrXaJU63V6yVkzgAzAAWACsqiM4ASZHMLRc7k8SFQmGwUFk6Wgqh6MBgeQAQswQMIqPovFTfLSyIzmcKWSFWQJYJxYGFmBFQgALKgwdIjZ5gBDUAD8+iAA

Comment: @Terry in your example you didn't reassign, but create a new object with the same values. Am I missing something?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42021 is the issue but it hasn't been classified as a bug... Shall I write up my findings as an answer or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @GergőHorváth Perhaps reassignment isn't the right word, but basically if you create a new const and point it to the same object reference, the error goes away. Could be a quick and dirty fix until TypeScript fixes the bug :)